# Next/React Hydration Failed Error in a functional React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a Next/React component that is a timer, that starts with the `new Date()` time when the user arrives to the component. It then resets after the timer gets to 0, starting the countdown of the next hour. I am getting an error from Next.js and I am not sure how to address it as I am using the suggested [useEffect and useState](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) provided in the error console.

Error: **Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "34" Client: "33"**

Error: **Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/App.module.css';

const Timer = () => {
  const now: Array<string> = new Date().toISOString()
    .split('.')[0]
    .split(':')

  const nowMin: number = parseInt(now[1]) * 60000,
    nowSec: number = parseInt(now[2]) * 1000,
    hour: number = 3600000, // one hour in milliseconds
    startTime: number = hour - (nowMin + nowSec),
    time: number = hour

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(startTime)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = counter > 0 &&
      setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(counter - 1000)
      }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer as any)
  }, [counter])

  if (counter === 0) {
    setCounter(time)
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.timer}>
      <span className={`${styles.code} ${styles.minutes}`}>
        {
          String(Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)))
            .padStart(2, '0')
        }
      </span>
      <span className={styles.colon}>:</span>
      <span className={`${styles.code} ${styles.seconds}`}>
        {
          String(Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000))
            .padStart(2, '0')
        }
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Timer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. You can [disable server side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) in Next.js. On the component importing the Timer component, disabling `ssr` removed that error. I hope this helps anyone else that is running into the react hydration error:

```
const Timer = dynamic(() => import('../components/timer'), {
  ssr: false
})

...

<Timer />
```